# Use a contained view controller to manage carousel animations or not?

Tags: ios

I have a requirement to implement a screen comprised as three portions and am wondering how best to tackle implementing it - either as one view controller which contains multiple views and manages them all, or have the middle portion of the screen managed by its own view controller which is contained within the other view controller.

- The red part of the screen will contain a background image, a couple of buttons, a tab, and some dynamic text. (It is not a navigation bar).
- The green part of the screen is just some static images and text.
- The blue part of the screen is a series of images that will be animated in some way (TBD) but an automatically rotating or sliding carousel is preferred. THe blue part extends between the red and green parts and will be covered whenever the purple or yellow parts appear.
- The purple part will programatically slide down and back up in order to display a message
- The yellow part will slide down and back up whenever the user drags and drops from a tab in the red part, it will contain some text and a button.

So my main question is should a separate contained VC manage the blue part of the screen to deal with the animation or could one VC just manage every view on the screen?

A secondary question is, is there a ready-make way to implement the dragging down and up of the yellow section?

This is for iOS5 and 5.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are plannig to use the "Container View" from the objects library, it doesn't gonna work with iOS 5, you could create another ViewController and add it to the Main VC but in that case you have to write more code to properly handle the controller:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6

It is a good idea to implement your custom Contained View Controller if you are going to reuse that VC and if you have to use iOS5

If you are not going to use that CVC again and you need iOS5+ I would use only one ViewController to manage all views.